# showing comparison if in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, expression, ternary-operator

I have problem with IF Expression ,

This expression shows settled and outstandings records.

```
value = ((java.lang.Boolean)field_paid.getValue()) == false ? "Yes" : "No";
```

This shows transaction number:

```
$F{transactionNumber}
```

How i can report only outstanding transactions?

Comment: Can you post some of your code beyond this?  I'm thinking you can use the iReport Filter Expression, or a Detail Band Print When depending on your needs.

Comment: I read your question thrice to understand and then came to the conclusion that PRINT WHEN is your solution!